# Get User Permission Data (PDO)

Tags: php, pdo, permissions

What i'm trying to do is make a function that gets a user permission level as seen here.

```
function userPermission($level, $conn){
    try{
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username = :Player AND level = :Level ";
        $s = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $s->bindValue(":Player", $_SESSION['username']);
        $s->bindValue(":Level", $level);
        $s->execute();
        return true;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
            error_log("PDOException: " . $e->getMessage());
            return false;
        }   

}
```

and once I go to the page and input the code that should in-tile the functionality of this function. It doesn't work at all.

Here is the code that I inputted

```
 <?php if (!userPermission('0', $conn) == 2) {
       echo '<input type="radio" id="tab-7" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-7">Permissions</label>';
    } else {
       echo '<input disabled=disabled type="radio" id="tab-7" name="tab-group-1">
       <label id="disabled" for="tab-7">Permissions</label>';
    }
    ?>
```

The 0 is the current level of the user and I was using that as a test, as for the  `== 3` that's what the rank has to be in order to access the tab

Anyways, I'm either doing this wrong or I don't know what i'm doing. I get no errors at all but the code I inputted seems unreliable.

Comment: Is there any error in your log? And `SELECT ? FROM` what is your selection?

Comment: Nope, I didn't get any errors and as for the `SELECT ? FROM`  that should be an asterix. I'm just getting  the username and level.

Comment: You're returning a boolean, but checking if it equals to 2? Also you're doing a select but not doing anything with the result.

Comment: What do you intend to happen if no row is found? The `SELECT` statement will succeed whether there is a match or not and you return `true` or `false` from it, but then you are using `userPermission(...) == 2` to compare its return value to `2`.  If you want to match values you'll need to fetch rows.

Comment: Please update this to show the current real code. You will attract answers pointing to the missing `*` in `SELECT * FROM`.

Comment: `function userPermission($level, $conn){
 try{
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username = :Player AND level = :Level ";
  $s = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $s->bindValue(":Player", $_SESSION['username']);
  $s->bindValue(":Level", $level);
  $s->execute();
 } catch(PDOException $e) {
   error_log("PDOException: " . $e->getMessage());
  }

  $row = $s->fetch();
  
  if($row[0] > 0)
  {
   return TRUE;
  }
  else
  {
   return FALSE;
  }
}` Would something like that work?

Comment: What is the name of the table column which holds the permission level?  You'll need to fetch and return that value from the statement after executing.

Comment: I'm not using a table for permissions. They're just added numerics to the level column. Here is an image of the table data http://i.imgur.com/13KBWkX.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code just execute but does not return the query result.
I modified your code a little bit as an example

```
function userPermission($username,$level, $conn){
    try{
        $sql = "SELECT `user_permission` 
                FROM `users` 
                WHERE username = :username AND level = :Level ";
        $s = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $s->bindValue(":username", $username);
        $s->bindValue(":level", $level);
        $s->execute();
        $row = $s->fetch();
        return $row['user_permission'];
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
            error_log("PDOException: " . $e->getMessage());
            return -1;
        }   
}
```

Make sure the session is set also

```
session_start();
$usermame = $_SESSION['username'];
if (!userPermission($username,'0', $conn) == 2) {...
```

Comment: I have session handled in a different file so I don't have to keep putting it in each file. Also, i'm trying to retrieve `level` not user_permission as I don't have that column.

Comment: @RyanFuhrman like I said it was an example, I trust that you smart enough to adjust it

Comment: Thanks! I did a different method that I used inner join with tables but thanks for the example.